# java.text.ParseException while converting string to date

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am a very beginner to java. I am new to this site.

I am trying to convert a string to date but i am getting parse exception.
Below is my code:
    I have the value in my variable myDateValue as `Wed May 15 00:00:00 IST 2013`

```
DateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
java.util.Date myDate = sdf1.parse(myDateValue);
java.sql.sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(myDate.getTime());
```

I get the below exception:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed May 15 00:00:00 IST
>   2013"

I also tried this but also it not worked:

```
DateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
String formatdate = sdf1.format(myDateValue);
java.util.Date myate = sdf1.parse(formatdate);
java.sql.sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(myate.getTime());
```

For this i got the below error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a
>   Date

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: 1st code: Does `Wed May 15 00:00:00 IST 2013` look like `dd-MM-yyyy`?

Comment: 2nd code: this should not even compile

Comment: @ThomasWeller : Sir that was just for information i was doing that. I have corrected can you please remove the downvote

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), `java.sql.Date`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format `dd-MMM-yyyy` is wrong. Your date looks like `Wed May 15 00:00:00 IST 2013`, so your format should be - `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy`.

See the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for in depth detail of pattern letters.

EDIT to address comment. If you want your date to be in `dd-MMM-yyyy` format you have to format it again -

```
SimpleDateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
Date date = originalFormat.parse(myDateValue);
SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd");
String myNewDate = newFormat.format(date);
```

Comment: I know i am getting date in the format specified by you but i want my date to be dd-MM-yyyy so i have used that format.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse(                    // Represent a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone.
    "23-Jan-2018" ,
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(    // Define a formatting pattern to match your input.
        "dd-MMM-uuuu" ,             // The modern parsing codes have changed a bit from legacy codes. Study the class documentation carefully.
        Locale.US                   // Specify a locale to determine a human language to use in translating the name of the month.
    )                               
)                                   // Returns a `LocalDate` object.
.toString()                         // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format to represent the value of this `LocalDate` object.
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/CMRIdX).

> 2018-01-23

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplanted the terrible old date-time classes (`Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`).

The old classes lacked a class to represent a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone. The `java.sql.Date` class pretended to do this, but actually held a moment, a date with time-of-day and offset-from-UTC.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

Define a formatting pattern to match your input.

```
String input = "23-Jan-2018" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uuuu" , Locale.US ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).